# Bootstrap DateTimePicker renders incorrectly

Tags: c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with datetimepicker. My calendar renders incorrectly in Chrome, although it is OK in Edge. Here is a screenshot from Chrome:
[image]

And here is a screenshot from Edge:

[image]

I am working on ASP.NET Core MVC project and here is my code from the view:

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Required field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AppointmentDate" name="date" placeholder="date">
                        <span @*class="focus-input100"*@></span>
                    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date_input = $('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var options = {
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        language: 'arm'
    };
    date_input.datepicker(options);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your css styles, but I suggest you to add this to the main div of your calendar:

```
#yourmaindiv{
 width: -webkit-fit-content;
 width: -o-fit-content;
 width: -moz-fit-content;
 width: fit-content;
}
```

Greetings.

Comment: Let me know if it is working, otherwise can you send me the stylesheet for this page.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day